# Is there a Unicode equivalent for `{\pGraph}` in Java / POSIX regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, unicode, posix, character-properties

According to the documentation of [java.util.Pattern](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), the POSIX character class `\p{Graph}` (`[:graph:]` in POSIX notation) matches *"a visible character: `[\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}]`"*. However, this is limited to ASCII characters only. Is there an equivalent class or expression for matching (visible) Unicode characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[^\p{Z}\p{C}]
```

Comment: According to the Unicode Regular Expressions standard, this expression means "anything other than a separator and a control character." http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Categories

Comment: Yep.  And if it ain't one of them, it's visible.